# Maximum enclosing circle algorithm with Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I'm new to spark and scala, I'm trying to implement the maximum enclosing circle algorithm. For input I have csv file with id,x,y:

```
id   x   y
1    1   0
2    1   2
1    0   0
3    5   10
...
```

Needs to find a max enclosing circle for each id.
I implemented the solution but it is not optimal.

```
val data = csv
  .filter(_ != header)
  .map(_.split(","))
  .map(col => (col(0), Location(col(2).toInt, col(3).toInt)))

val idLoc = data.groupByKey()
val ids = idLoc.keys.collect().toList.par
ids.foreach {
  case id =>
    val locations = data.filter(_._1 == id).values.cache()
    val maxEnclCircle = findMaxEnclCircle(findEnclosedPoints(locations, eps))
}

def findMaxEnclCircle(centroids: RDD[(Location, Long)]): Location = {
  centroids.max()(new Ordering[(Location, Long)]() {
    override def compare(x: (Location, Long), y: (Location, Long)): Int =
      Ordering[Long].compare(x._2, y._2)
  })._1
}
def findEnclosedPoints(locations: RDD[Location], eps: Double): RDD[(Location, Long)] = {
  locations.cartesian(locations).filter {
    case (a, b) => isEnclosed(a, b, eps)
  }.map { case (a, b) => (a, 1L) }.reduceByKey(_ + _)
}
```

As you can see I keep a list of id in the memory. How can I improve the code to get rid of it?

Thanks.

Comment: You probably mean the minimum enclosing circle? For maximum just do `radius = Infinity` ;-)

Comment: Maybe I'm not very well named algorithm. By "maximum enclosing circle algorithm" I mean the search for a circle of a given radius (eps) with the maximum number of points inside.

Comment: that helps, but I'm not sure I follow the code. Why does the circle need to have one point at its center? It does nos seem to me to be doing what you are saying.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with your code above is that you are not using the cluster! When you do `collect()` all your data is sent to the single master and all computations are done there. For efficiency, use `aggregateByKey()` to shuffle all the point with the same id to the same executor, then do the computation there.